# Gnuplot: 3D Surface Outline

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a simple 3D surface in GNUPlot for the following function:

```
f(x,y)=x**2-y**2
```

This works fine. However I would like to only display the outline of the surface. Without the colors or grid lines along it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is an example of what I am looking to create:
[Outline of the surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TedfX.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a general solution. In your special case I would consider just drawing each single line using `parametric` mode like in this script:

```
f(x,y) = x**2 - y**2

set parametric
set urange [-10:10]
set vrange [-10:10]

set nokey
#set border 0   # uncomment to remove the axes
#unset xtics
#unset ytics
#unset ztics

set arrow 1 from 0,0,0 to 0,0,100
set arrow 1 head lw 2

splot   u,-10,f(  u,-10) lc 0,  \
        u, 10,f(  u, 10) lc 0,  \
      -10,  v,f(-10,  v) lc 0,  \
       10,  v,f( 10,  v) lc 0,  \
        u,  0,f(  u,  0) lc 0
```

This is the result:

[image: Outline]

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you could also adjust the number of isolines drawn by gnuplot:

```
f(x,y) = x**2 - y**2
set xr [-10:10]
set yr [-10:10]
unset key
set isosamples 2,3
splot f(x,y)
```

[image]